# Setting rounded corners and image to a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to make button'corners round, as well as setting a background image. Though I was able to achieve button with rounded corners, but not to set the image as the background. When I try `android:drawableTop:@drawable/filename`, the button is again converted to its default shape and text goes below the image, but I want the image as the background, so how to apply both the things(rounded corner and background image) to the button?

I have created an xml file named `button_shape` in drawable; the code for it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

android:shape="rectangle"
>

<solid android:color="#ffffff"
     />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

and the main xml file code where I have put the button is:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="179dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    />
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Hi ,I got Whhat you specified when Clean Project  :)

Answer (score 0):

use this in shape

```
solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

and imageview should be

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:scaleType="fitXY"   android:background="@drawable/shape"     
     android:src="@drawable/yourimage" />
```

Comment: hey thanx for the reply but i m using button not imageview .... can u tel me for a button???

Answer (score 0):

> Use this background.xml put in Drowable and set on Button android:background="@drawable/ background" and ovel_shape is xml file in drawable where you can put code for rounded corners

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/rounded_corn"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ovel_shape"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/background_img"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image"/>

</layer-list>
```